# phpMyAdmin frustrating me

Tags: time, phpmyadmin, config

In the phpMyAdmin config file "/etc/phpmyadmn/config.inc.php"

I have the settings:

```
$cfg['MaxRows']         = 200;
$cfg['UploadDir']       = '';
$cfg['SaveDir']         = '';
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']       = 0;  
$cfg['MemoryLimit']     = 0;
$cfg['ThemeDefault']        = 'original';
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 3600*24*3;        // Set timeout to 3 days
```

which should set my session to stay open 3 days, but instead it goes out every 20 minutes.  This is so frustrating when doing DB syncing and maint, as the session times out many times before you can finish writing the query you need, so have to always create it in a "scratch pad" and try keeping the session refreshed.

I've lost so much data and hand entering it again over and over is just insane!

Something has to be overriding what values I've given it.  I started at just 2 hours and kept increasing, but nothing at all effects this.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your PHP-session gets cleaned up.
Increase the value of the PHP-setting session.gc_maxlifetime

Comment: Correct. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_LoginCookieValidity for more details

Comment: Ah! Maxlifetime was what I was looking for!  Thanks!